# Ocelot Gateway duplicate query params

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, gateway, ocelot

I am using ocelot gateway.

Here is the example configuration

```
{
  "DownstreamPathTemplate": "/ipgeo?apiKey={key}&ip={ip}",
  "DownstreamScheme": "http",
  "DownstreamHostAndPorts": [
    {
      "Host": "api.ipgeolocation.io",
      "Port": 80
    }
  ],
  "UpstreamHttpMethod": ["GET"],
  "UpstreamPathTemplate": "/GLI/secondary?apiKey={key}&ip={ip}"
}
```

As you can see, there are two query params. When I send a request using postman:

```
http://localhost:5000/GLI/secondary?apiKey=aaa&ip=8.8.8.8
```

OCELOT get duplicate query params and generate a downstream url like this:

```
 http://api.ipgeolocation.io/ipgeo?apiKey=aaa&ip=8.8.8.8&apiKey=aaa&ip=8.8.8.8
```

Console screen:

```
info: Ocelot.Requester.Middleware.HttpRequesterMiddleware[0]
  requestId: 0HMFNFVDSDQH9:0000000A, previousRequestId: no previous request id, message: 301 (Moved Permanently) status code, request uri: http://api.ipgeolocation.io/ipgeo?apiKey=aaa&ip=8.8.8.8&apiKey=aaa&ip=8.8.8.8
```

How can I change this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Same problem,

For me works use this syntax, basically I have removed the "?" symbol in the `UpstreamPathTemplate`:

```
"DownstreamPathTemplate": "/GLI/secondary?{everything}"

"UpstreamPathTemplate": "/GLI/secondary{everything}"
```

Comment: that was so usefull thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
"DownstreamPathTemplate": "/ipgeo?{everything}"
```

```
"UpstreamPathTemplate": "/GLI/secondary?{everything}"
```

OR

```
"UpstreamPathTemplate": "/GLI/secondary/{everything}"
```